# Can't get full url when setting local PAC file

Tags: javascript, url, browser, pac

I'm writing a .pac file for browser. I want browser to check   url that i enter matches the rules.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    url=url.toLowerCase();
    host=host.toLowerCase();
    debugPAC ="PAC Debug Information\n";
    debugPAC +="-----------------------------------\n";
    debugPAC +="Machine IP: " + myIpAddress() + "\n";
    debugPAC +="Hostname: " + host + "\n";
    if (isResolvable(host)) {resolvableHost = "True"} else {resolvableHost = "False"};
    debugPAC +="Host Resolvable: " + resolvableHost + "\n";
    debugPAC +="Hostname IP: " + dnsResolve(host) + "\n";
    if (isPlainHostName(host)) {plainHost = "True"} else {plainHost = "False"};
    debugPAC +="Plain Hostname: " + plainHost + "\n";
    debugPAC +="Domain Levels: " + dnsDomainLevels(host) + "\n";
    debugPAC +="URL: " + url + "\n";
    if (url.substring(0,5)=="http:") {protocol="HTTP";}
    else if (url.substring(0,6)=="https:") {protocol="HTTPS";} 
    else if (url.substring(0,4)=="ftp:") {protocol="FTP";}
    else {protocol="Unknown";}
    debugPAC +="Protocol: " + protocol + "\n";
    if (!shExpMatch(url,"*.(js|xml|ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|css|swf)*")) {alert(debugPAC);}
    if(shExpMatch(url,"*://login.dangdang.com/images/bg/dataimg/dly_0807_01*"))
    {
        var noproxy=url;
        alert("noproxy4simplejpg"+noproxy);
        return "PROXY 192.168.0.101:808";
    }
    if(shExpMatch(url,"*://login.dangdang.com/script/sign_in2011.js"))
    {
        var noproxy=url;
        alert("noproxy4js"+noproxy);
        return "DIRECT";
    }
    if(shExpMatch(url,"*login.dangdang.com/*.gif*"))
    {
        var noproxy=url;
        alert("noproxy4gif"+noproxy);
        return "DIRECT";
    }
    if(shExpMatch(url,"*login.dangdang.com/*"))
    {
        var proxy=url;
        alert("proxy4login"+proxy);
        return "PROXY 192.168.0.101:808";
    }
    else
        return  "DIRECT"; 
}
```

The question is that i want to receive the complete url from browser rather than protocol and host . But now i can only receive `url` such as `https://www.login.dngdang.com/` by testing, but i entered `https://www.login.dangdang.com/xxx`. what's wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "get"?

Comment: I wrote some javascript to check parameter 'url' in the function.
Below is the javascript:
    debugPAC +="Machine IP: " + myIpAddress() + "\n";
    debugPAC +="Hostname: " + host + "\n";
    debugPAC +="URL: " + url + "\n";
     if (!shExpMatch(url,"*.(js|xml|ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|css|swf)*")) {alert(debugPAC);}
     I enter 'https://www.login.dangdang.com/xxx' ,but the function receive 'https://www.login.dangdang.com/'.why? I read the reference ,it said what you enter what  receive.

Comment: You can update your own question; Put codes into your question to make it more answerable. Also, are you using some debugging tool? Because as far as I remember, `alert` does not work in PAC because it's a method of `window`, not part of ECMAScript.

Comment: Alert does work in PAC. And I have searched some reference and found it can be used. MY browser works well too by using altert.
About the debugging tool, Now google has a tool named pacparser could debug it ,but it does work ONLY on 32 bit computer, but my computer is 64 bit, so i cannot be able to use it at present.
Now, what I want to konw most is whether browser sends url ignore the path or not?

Comment: eg. when entering https://external1.collaboration.pc.com/external/default.aspx
The url result is https://external1.collaboration.pc.com, the other path is disapper.And I want to kown more about how the borwser engine work for it? So could you please help me look into it and share your comments? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wonder what browser you're using, because Chrome and Firefox seem to suppress `alert`, only IE accept that. And even IE6 get the correct result. Are you sure you're posting the correct code? E.g. not accidentally wrote `url=host.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: I use IE 10, it works well.Firefox and Chrome do not support it.I checked code many times.I could recrive the alert message but the other path is disapper.

Answer (score 3):

I see your URL uses HTTPS - https://www.login.dangdang.com/xxx

The path and query components of https:// URLs are stripped for security reasons by browsers by default.

In Chrome, you can disable this by setting PacHttpsUrlStrippingEnabled to false

In Firefox the preference is network.proxy.autoconfig_url.include_path.

> Browsers strip privacy and security sensitive parts of https:// URLs
>   before passing them on to PAC scripts (Proxy Auto Config) during proxy resolution.
>
> When True, the security feature is enabled, and https:// URLs are
>   stripped before submitting them to a PAC script. In this manner the
>   PAC script is not able to view data that is ordinarily protected by an
>   encrypted channel (such as the URL's path and query).
>
> When False, the security feature is disabled, and PAC scripts are
>   implicitly granted the ability to view all components of an https://
>   URL. This applies to all PAC scripts regardless of origin (including
>   those fetched over an insecure transport, or discovered insecurely
>   through WPAD).
>
> This defaults to True (security feature enabled).

It is recommended that this be set to True. The only reason to set it to False is if it causes a compatibility problem with existing PAC scripts.

Comment: It's 2022 and I just realized this. What a pity, this makes the `url` parameter in `FindProxyForURL` completely useless. I'm writing my own PAC file so I can disable this with confident, but still.